# Alternatives to whisper database

Tags: database, graphite, whisper

I am using graphite + whisper for monitoring the system metrics but since the number of metrics are increasing , it is becoming difficult to use whisper as a storage as it is not an optimal solution because of inode table bottleneck and also it is not scalable.

Anyone has suggestions which database will be good in place of whisper which can solve inode table bottleneck problem and is also scalable and fast.

Comment: How many metrics are you storing that you get those problems? Question is highly subjective.

Comment: I have a million metrics per minute.

Comment: 1m/min should not cause any problems

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I might suggest checking out HostedGraphite.com (if you're willing to migrate to a hosted solution so youdon't need to worry about managing this yourself, and of course, willing to pay for the service)

Comment: @tonyennis thanks for the suggestion i will look forward to it....